# Enumerate recurring events from Outlook via ODATA

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-calendar, recurring-events

I am using ODATA (specifically Kingsway Software Premium ODATA Source Editor) to connect SSIS to Outlook calendars and import the calendar events into a SQL Server table.

According to the Microsoft Graph API documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) the List Events method will return single events, and recurring event masters from the calendar.  For recurring events, I can derive the individual events based on the data in the recurring_* columns returned via the ODATA data source.

The problem that I am having is how to gather event information if one or more of the events within the recurring event are modified (ie changing start/end dates) or if an instance within the recurring event is deleted.  Changing or deleting an occurrence within a recurring series does not change the event to a single event, so I'm at a loss as to how I can get the details for such events.

This screenshot shows how a daily recurring event from 10:00 - 11:00 has been modified to 12:00 - 13:00.  Also note that the icon representing a recurring event has been struck through.

[image]

After loading the calendar into SQL Server, the resulting data still only shows the master, and other singe events.  The entry that was modified to go from 12:00 - 13:00 doesn't appear.   When a single instance within the recurring event is deleted, it also doesn't change anything within the master event.

[image]

Any ideas on what I need to do to capture changes and deletes within recurring masters?